# fields of login page not updating as filled in

Tags: html, vba, dom, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to login to a webpage using VBA & IE automation. I'm hitting what I've been able to solve on other websites, but not this one. When I "click" on the login button of the site it then tells me that the user name & password are empty, when they are not. I've tried pauses. setting focus, setting the field as active & dispatching events, but so far nothing has worked with the website.

```
Dim HTMLInputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLInputElement
Dim HTMLInput2 As MSHTML.IHTMLInputElement
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 
Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLButtonElement
Dim HTMLLinks As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLLink As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 

'make IE visible then open website
IE.Visible = True
'IE.top = 0
'IE.Left = 0
IE.width = 1200
IE.height = 800                                       '

IE.Navigate funcLookupURL(strMGA, strCO)                        'https://agency.hciharmony.com/login

'check if internet explorer is ready otherwise loop til it is
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
'    Debug.Print "1"
'    Debug.Print IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
'login
Dim evt As Object
Dim evt2 As Object
Dim evt3 As Object
Dim evt4 As Object
Set evt = IE.Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
Set evt2 = IE.Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
Set evt3 = IE.Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
Set evt4 = IE.Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")

evt.initEvent "blur", False, True
evt2.initEvent "focus", False, True
evt3.initEvent "input", True, False
evt4.initEvent "change", True, False 

'<input name="username" class="auth0-lock-input" type="text" placeholder="username/email" value="TTC-201" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off">
Set HTMLInput = IE.Document.querySelector("input[placeholder='username/email']") 

HTMLInput.focus
Sleep 500
HTMLInput.setActive
Sleep 500
HTMLInput.Value = funcLookupUserName(strMGA, strCO)
HTMLInput.setAttribute "value", funcLookupUserName(strMGA, strCO)
HTMLInput.innerText = funcLookupUserName(strMGA, strCO)

Sleep 500

'HTMLInput.dispatchEvent evt
'HTMLInput.dispatchEvent evt2
'HTMLInput.dispatchEvent evt3
'HTMLInput.dispatchEvent evt4

IE.Document.dispatchEvent evt
IE.Document.dispatchEvent evt2

IE.Document.dispatchEvent evt3
IE.Document.dispatchEvent evt4
Sleep 500

'<input name="password" class="auth0-lock-input" type="password" placeholder="your password" value="xxxsomevalueherexxx" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off">

Set HTMLInput2 = IE.Document.querySelector("input[placeholder='your password']")
HTMLInput2.focus
Sleep 500
HTMLInput2.setActive
Sleep 500
HTMLInput2.Value = funcLookupPassword(strMGA, strCO)             'password
HTMLInput2.innerText = funcLookupPassword(strMGA, strCO)             'password
HTMLInput2.setAttribute "value", funcLookupPassword(strMGA, strCO)            'password
Sleep 500
'HTMLInput2.dispatchEvent evt
'HTMLInput2.dispatchEvent evt2
'HTMLInput2.dispatchEvent evt3
'HTMLInput2.dispatchEvent evt4

IE.Document.dispatchEvent evt
IE.Document.dispatchEvent evt2
IE.Document.dispatchEvent evt3
IE.Document.dispatchEvent evt4
Sleep 500

'IE.Document.querySelector("input[placeholder='your password']").dispatchEvent evt

 
'i've tried submitting the form too instead of clicking the button
'IE.Document.Forms(0).submit

 
'Click sign in
Set HTMLButton = IE.Document.querySelector("button[type='submit']")
HTMLButton.focus
Sleep 500
HTMLButton.setActive
Sleep 3000
HTMLButton.Click
Debug.Print "Clicked Sign-in
```

I've tried submitting the form instead of clicking the button. That does not work either. This code does not pause for the website to load yet, but I manually step thru it so that's not my problem. I see the value's appear on the fields in IE & in the deveoper tools the value attribute fills in with a value. I've dispatched events on the fields as well as IE.document. I've tried combinations of. My last version which i'm posting here, used blur, change, input & focus. It looks to me like event listeners are mostly on the main document. When I try to login, the values drop out of the text boxes & they get highlighted in red with "cannot be blank". I know very little on dispatch events so i'm mainly guessing here. any advice would be appreciated.

edit:

```
'topBlur
'  dispatchEvent: function (topLevelType, nativeEvent) {
'    if (!ReactEventListener._enabled) {
'      return;
'    }
'
'    var bookKeeping = TopLevelCallbackBookKeeping.getPooled(topLevelType, nativeEvent);
'    try {
'      // Event queue being processed in the same cycle allows
'      // `preventDefault`.
'      ReactUpdates.batchedUpdates(handleTopLevelImpl, bookKeeping);
'    } finally {
'      TopLevelCallbackBookKeeping.release(bookKeeping);
'    }
'  }
'};
```

this function fired on clicking the login button. everything seems to say "topblur". not sure what it means.
Also, when i type in the user id, this div changes from

changes too . Then changes back when focus lost.

Comment: I tried to visit the commented URL from the code but the site is not loading and shows some error in the console with a blank page. So I am not able to test the above code. I suggest trying to open the dev tools and try to manually enter the values in the field. check what changes occur in the source code. It may give some hint. Just after setting the value for a single element try to dispatch the 'change' event. If possible, let us know how to visit this site so that we can make some tests with the code or try to provide the HTML code to test it.

Comment: Deepak, thank you. the website link is good, although it'll redirect on loading. It was probably down for maintenance.  https://typtap.com/ this is the home page, then upper right "agents", then on next page choose the option for Florida (left side). That'll take you to the same harmony login. I tried dispatching ` Set evt4 = IE.Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents") evt4.initEvent "change", True, False  IE.Document.dispatchEvent evt4 `  after the username & password were each updated, so twice. i also added keydown & up events. none worked. I tried looking at where events fire, adding to my ?

Comment: paste bin of the website added:  https://pastebin.com/5iam1PjN

Comment: and one more past bin  https://pastebin.com/JJx05DUG

Comment: When I try to visit the site it shows [these warnings](https://imgur.com/a/9arb3OX) in the console with a blank page. I try to make a test with your sample HTML code and I can enter the values in the fields but there is no validation occur when I click the button. Possible because I am running the page locally and it shows Auth related errors while clicking the button. So still I am not able to reproduce it. I got these warnings and errors in all browsers. So you can check and let us know if you see a similar issue on your side.

Comment: Deepak. I get the DOM7011 error as well, but not the other script errors. Interestingly the errors occur on the password field only. the website is sensitive even logining manually. if i choose my user idea from IE memorizing it, when i click into the password field it erases the user id. I have to type it or ctl-v paste it. so it likes keyboard commands & the password field seems to trigger something more so than the user id. If I run my code, is there away for me to see if my dispatch events are actually affecting the page?

Comment: Ok, quick update. i changed my events to HTMLInput2.dispatchEvent evt5 since IE shows an event listen attached to each field. i get Script70:Permission denied Login(15,1592) when I run them.

Comment: When i do IE.Document.dispatchEvent evt5 I get no response from the console. no errors but I don't know if it's reacting to it or not. I'm trying to fire 3 events. keydown, keyup, change. I'm thinking i might need to do them all in order, so starting with focus & ending with blur?

Comment: One more updated. next time I ran the job with  IE.Document.dispatchEvent I got console errors as well. I do see an "invalid" event on the username/password fields i'm going to try tomorrow. I'm not confident with the true/false in the various event calls like "evt.initEvent "blur", False, True"  as far as what they mean & which i should choose as well.

Comment: I am not sure how you are able to access this site. I try to access the site from multiple devices with the same issue. Do you mean you are getting the errors in the VBA or you are seeing these errors in the developer tools? I suggest trying to make a test with the [Application.SendKeys()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement). It will work in a similar way as the user is entering the values manually.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's giving you trouble pulling it up. It redirects here: https://ashton-prod.auth0.com/login?state=g6Fo2SBjSUhEZ3p4UlljQ1c0elFURXNfTUJBbzVVcWhvMjJaNaN0aWTZIEI2NWg4eVRsNnpQVUExSmZTenl2NnpVRC1IczQ1bUJTo2NpZNkgN1JLMUJ4Z252dnZYMUp0UWtkOXpHamRYZ3BscDB0alU&client=7RK1BxgnvvvX1JtQkd9zGjdXgplp0tjU&protocol=oauth2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fagency.hciharmony.com&scope=openid%20profile%20email&response_type=code&response_mode=query&nonce=bUI1QlVucWlCaFV4TFBiclQ4RX5iUEpsQVNOYklxV0JaZ3BrQWNtZmlTLQ%3D%3D&code_challenge

Comment: =Meo_E_YpqOVTRYIUuCzd2JAp8KLdhHcIMbKOCbSXM1o&code_challenge_method=S256&auth0Client=eyJuYW1lIjoiYXV0aDAtc3BhLWpzIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6IjEuMTAuMCJ9  this is the 2nd half of the url. including the leading =. I'll try next week more options. I want to avoid send keys if I can, but maybe i'll have to. I got the errors in IE event console. I could see them as my code fired.

Comment: is it possible to dispatch this event "dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:139)" i found on the website?

Comment: so this seems to be the function that the ReactEventHandler calls  ``` dispatchEvent: function (topLevelType, nativeEvent) {
    if (!ReactEventListener._enabled) {
      return;
    } ```  I'm wondering is it possible to remove an eventlistner with vba & bypass it that way. I read somewhere that ReactEvent uses synthetic events & not those native to the browser so I think that's why i get errors when I dispatch events?

Comment: The last URL you had shared in the comment worked for me and I made a test. I found that while clicking the submit button it clears the fields and shows validation message for empty fields. Sadly there is no JS events in the HTML code. I tried to make a test with the Onchange event but it also did not worked. As per my knowledge, we cannot manipulate the  React-js events using VBA.

Comment: Deepak, I'm going to try an idea or two this week. If they fail i'm going to settle on sendkeys. I'll post back as to what the final method is. Thank you for your help on this.

Comment: Thanks for updating us with the current status of the issue. you can make a test and let us know. We will try to provide further suggestions if needed. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Deepak, I tried a few variations to alert the website it was updated. no joy however. I did use SendKeys and that worked. It shuts of the users numbers lock, but I can live with it. SendKeys was successful.

Comment: From your last comment, I can see that by using the SendKeys() the issue can be solved. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying many methods, I am left with VBA sendkeys as the answer.

```
HTMLInput.focus
Sleep 500
HTMLInput.setActive
Sleep 500
SendKeys strUname, True
```

after focusing on the target field. Then doing the same to the password. But it does work.